# How to implement dropdown list in a grid for kendoUI for angular. Can't find any documentation

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

Something like [this](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/cascading-dropdown-editors). But this example is for kendoUI for jquery. I need documentation for kendoUI for angular.

Comment: Have a look at the KendoUI grid docs. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/editing/custom-reactive-editing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do it in my application.  Here is a simple version of it:

**HTML Template**

```
<kendo-grid [data]="someData" [height]="750">
  <kendo-grid-column field="LaborType" title="Task" width="120">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      {{ GetLaborTypeDesc(dataItem.LaborType)?.LaborTypeDesc }}
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate>
      <kendo-dropdownlist [defaultItem]="{LaborTypeID: null, LaborTypeDesc: 'Select a task...'}" [data]="LaborTypes"
        textField="LaborTypeDesc" valueField="LaborTypeID" [valuePrimitive]="true">
      </kendo-dropdownlist>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

**Typescript**

```
  LaborTypes: Array<{ LaborTypeDesc: string, LaborTypeID: number }> = [];

  public GetLaborTypeDesc(id: number): any {
    return this.LaborTypes.find(x => x.LaborTypeID === id);
  }
```

I have Add, Edit, and Delete commands in my grid that involves a form not seen here.  I populate the `LaborTypes` object array in my `ngOnInit` function as well, so the user has options to choose in the dropdown.